# How to add each food to own food category in realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have nested class like this:

```
struct Category {
    let name : String
    let foods : [Food]
}

struct Food {
    let name : String
    let price : Double
}

let categories = [
    Category(name: "Breakfast", foods : [
        Food(name: "Hafta İçi Kahvaltısı", price: 18.0),
        Food(name: "Pazar Kahvaltısı", price: 25.0),
        Food(name: "Diyet Kahvaltı", price: 22.0),
        Food(name: "Köy Kahvaltısı", price: 15.0),
        Food(name: "Ege Kahvaltısı", price: 30.0)]),
    Category(name: "Hamburger", foods : [
        Food(name: "Big TezBurger", price: 26.0),
        Food(name: "TezRoyal", price: 24.0),
        Food(name: "Double TezzBurger", price: 17.0),
        Food(name: "TezChicken", price: 21.0),
        Food(name: "Köfteburger", price: 28.0)])
]
```

I want above structure in `Realm` database.

First of all I created `Category` table(class) in Realm with below codes:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var categoryDB = Category()
categoryDB.name = "Breakfasts"
try! realm.write {
     realm.add(categoryDB)
  }
```

After I created `Category` table, I added below codes for fill the `Food` table for each category

```
categoryDB.name = "Breakfasts"
categoryDB.foods[0].name = "Hafta İçi Kahvaltısı"
categoryDB.foods[0].price = 18.0

categoryDB.name = "Breakfasts"
categoryDB.foods[1].name = "Köy Kahvaltısı"
categoryDB.foods[1].price = 20.0
```

But I get an error like `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 0 is out of bounds (must be less than 0).'`

Conclusion: I need to have 5 different breakfast in `Breakfast` category and 5 different foods in `Lunch`category. There is no `Food` list data under my `Category` table as a `foods` property.

My detail realm studio screen in the link

https://youtu.be/WXnxDA15Rho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `categoryDB`, its `foods` is empty. That is the reason why you are getting index out of bounds exception.

You want to create `Food` and append it to `categoryDB.foods`.

```swift
let categoryDB = CategoryDB()

categoryDB.name = "Breakfasts"

let food1 = Food()
food1.name = "Hafta İçi Kahvaltısı"
food1.price = 18.0

let food2 = Food()
food2.name = "Köy Kahvaltısı"
food2.price = 20.0

categoryDB.foods.append(objectsIn: [food1 , food2])

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(categoryDB)
}
```

Comment: I saw ‘append’ functionality in document but it was used with filter function and I confused. I did not think simple :)